# How can I use a variable as a filename in a file path to store a numpy array in a numpy file?

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
for filename in os.listdir('/home/Downloads/nightlight_geotiffs'):
    if filename.endswith('.tif'):           # take TIFF-files only
        with rasterio.open(os.path.join('/home/ripperflo/Downloads/nightlight_geotiffs', filename)) as f:           # open GeoTiff and store in f
            img = f.read()          # open GeoTiff as 3D numpy array
            matrix = img[0]         # 3D array to 2D array because nighlight images has only one band
            z_norm = stats.zscore(matrix)           # normalize 2D array

            # save to npy file
            np.save('/home/Downloads/nightlight_z-array/', filename, z_norm)
```

The Code is running so far. the only thing i need to know is: how can I save the numpy array as .npy file with the same name as the origin input file? So the input file is called 'BJ2012_2.tif' and the output file should be called 'BJ2012_2.npy'.

Comment: have you tried using string formmating?

Comment: No, I am a beginner and do not know many techniques.

Comment: okay, file = filename.split('.')[0], will give the the name without the ('.tif') then new_filename= f'{file}.npz'

Comment: I suggest you use [`os.path,splitext()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) to get the name without an extension (as well as the extension itself).

Comment: Unfortunately not. Perhaps I have expressed myself incorrectly.The file read out at the beginning should be converted and at the end with the same name except for the ending, which is given by np.save to be saved in a new folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Also, try passing in variables rather than hardcoding especially paths

```
DIR = '/home/Downloads/nightlight_geotiffs'
files = [x for x in os.listdir(DIR) if x.endswith('.tif')] # gives you all the list of ('.tif files')
NUMPY_DIR = '/home/Downloads/nightlight_z-array/'

for file in files:
    path = os.path.join(DIR, file)
    with open(path,'r') as f:            
        img = f.read()                    
        matrix = img[0]                    
        z_norm = stats.zscore(matrix)           
        file= file.split('.')[0]
        new_file= os.path.join(NUMPY_DIR,f'{file}')
        
       # save to npy file
        np.save(new_file, z_norm)
```

Comment: oh, missed the np.save args. Please try again

Comment: the code creates a file named 'nightlight_z-array.npy'in the folder Downloads

Comment: np,.save(filename, data)... whereas, we just passed in the folder name instead. Please try again. Also ensure that z_norm has actual data  in it.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ripperflo/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/z-norm_geotiff2.py", line 22, in <module>
    new_file = os.path(NUMPY_DIR, f'{file}.npy')
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: sorry sleepy eyes. it should be os.path.join()

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File or directory not found: '/home/Downloads/nightlight_z-array/BJ2012_1.npz.npy'.

Comment: i don't know if we are getting at the same thing. the code works so far. i just can't get the file to be saved as an npy file at the end to have the same name as the original file that is read in at the beginning.

Comment: '/home/Downloads/nightlight_z-array/BJ2012_1.npz.npy'. <---there is  the error i have updated the code, apparently we dont need to add the file extension

Answer (score 0):

How about extracting the filename string without the last 4 characters?

```
np.save('/home/Downloads/nightlight_z-array/' + str(filename)[0:-4], z_norm)
```

Comment: generates error:FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File or directory not found: '/home/Downloads/nightlight_z-array/.npy'.

Comment: sorry I've updated my code... by the way, does the path `/home/Downloads/nightlight_z-array/` exist?